# Python sub object deletion order

Tags: python, del

I am trying understand how the python object `__del__()` method works.  Here's an example that I am trying test:

```
class Hello(object):

    def __init__(self, arg1="hi"):
        print("in Hello __init__()")
        self.obj = SubObj()

    def __del__(self):
        print("in Hello __del__()")

    def test(self):
        print('in Hello obj.test().')


class SubObj(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1="hi"):
        print("in SubObj __init__()")

    def __del__(self):
        print("in SubObj __del__()")

    def test(self):
        print('in SubObj obj.test().')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello = Hello()
    from time import sleep

    hello.test()

    sleep(4)
```

So the output of that program is the following:

```
$ python test_order.py 
in Hello __init__()
in SubObj __init__()
in Hello obj.test().
in Hello __del__()
in SubObj __del__()
```

Is the `SubObj` always deleted first?  Is it safe to assume that `Hello` object was deleted after the `in SubObj __del__()`.  Is there a way to verify the order in which the deletion works?

Comment: I don't know why you think `SubObj` is deleted first, considering `in Hello __del__()` gets printed first.

Comment: I think the procedure is 1. Program end. 2. Opps, program end, delete things we have, ar ha it is `Hello()`. 3. Why there is something left? Where is its parent? No? Delete it.

Answer (score 0):

As you see from the output, the `Hello` object `hello` gets deleted first because `hello.obj` still holds a reference to the `SubObj` object. After `hello` is deleted there is no longer any reference to the `SubObj` object, it is therefore deleted then.

Comment: Are you sure its not that Hello object deletion started, then it looks to delete the SubObj as it is going through Hello object component?